# Sending getblocks message but not getting inv message response

Tags: protocol, message

I am building my own bitcoin client, and I have most of the protocol working from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_Specification.

I successfully make a connection with the version and verack commands. And when I send a ping, I get back a pong with the same nonce.

The problem I am having now is that I don't get the expected response to my getblocks message. I build the block locator using the hash of the genesis block header, and I serialize the message and send it.

But then I don't get the inv message with MSG_BLOCK like I expect.

These are the raw bytes that I send as my getblocks message:

```
f9beb4d9676574626c6f636b73000000450000008634d5ae0100000001000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is built following the specification here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_Specification#getblocks.

Comment: Your question got cut off!

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: Just guessing: try reversing the order of char[32] of the hash. I'm doing offline blockchain analysis and it's stored as trailing zeroes, not leading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually do receive the inv message. The problem is in the way that I try to decode the inv message.

The getblocks message seems to work fine.